# Rails/Active Record polymorphic association needed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, polymorphism

I have 3 models, a **School** which has many **Teachers** and **Students**. The problem is that **Students** can belong to either a **School** or a **Teacher**, so theoretically they always belong to a **School** through association. How would I deal with this type of data structure in Rails/Active Record?

```
    class School < AR::Base
      has_many :teachers
      has_many :students

    end

    class Teacher < AR::Base
      belongs_to :school
      has_many :students

    end

    class Student < AR::Base
      belongs_to ???

    end
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution should work, but you I have a doubt about your introduction ; you say that "a teacher have many student". This sentences implies "a student has ONE teacher".

Maybe you should set an has_and_belongs_to_many association.

```
class School < AR::Base
  has_many :teachers
  has_many :students, :through => :teachers
end

class Teacher < AR::Base
  belongs_to :school
  has_many :students
end

class Student < AR::Base
  belongs_to :teacher
  belongs_to :school, :through => :teacher
end
```

Comment: To clarify, a teacher can have many students. The largest issue is that a student doesn't have to have a teacher at all, it can just belong to a school with no teacher relationship at all.

Comment: So the previous solution, without the "through", should work. But your  school students will not be the students of the teachers of the school.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you need polymarphic association, can be done as

```
class School < AR::Base
 has_many :teachers
 has_many :students, :as => :studentable
end

class Teacher < AR::Base
 belongs_to :school
 has_many :students
end

class Student < AR::Base
 belongs_to :studentable
end
```

don't forget to add studentable_id and studentable_type to student model.